# parsing PHP error log issue – line-breaks (\n) inside the error messages

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse PHP error log. The issue is that breaking the file by `\n` doesn't work.

```
explode(PHP_EOL, $log)
```

This doesn't work because there are some error messages that contain `\n` by itself.

How to break such file by lines then?

Extract of the problematic log:

```
[04-Jan-2012 21:28:48] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant AY_FACEBOOK_TAB_URL - assumed 'AY_FACEBOOK_TAB_URL' in /var/www/[hidden]/default.layout.tpl.php on line 36
[04-Jan-2012 22:38:02] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant AY_FACEBOOK_TAB_URL - assumed 'AY_FACEBOOK_TAB_URL' in /var/www/[hidden]/default.layout.tpl.php on line 36
[04-Jan-2012 23:43:33] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/4294967295/picture?type=large): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
 in /var/www/[hidden]/result.tpl.php on line 11
[04-Jan-2012 23:43:33] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: image in /var/www/[hidden]/result.tpl.php on line 20
```

Notice the line break after `HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: You need to be more specific. With the linebreak conditions at least. How would you know which `LF` ends a line, and which are just in between? Show an example.

Comment: It would be good if you provide some examples of the log. (Both with and without the line breaks in the error message.)

Comment: The answer would really depend on what you're trying to do with the data.  What's the reason for parsing the PHP log?

Comment: Why not just read the file line by line with SplFileObject?

Comment: @mario, simple. `str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), array("\nN_BREAK", "\rR_BREAK"), [..])` tells me that all file consists only `\n` breaks.

Comment: Can you add a small sample of your log file here with line breaks in the message as well.

Comment: @GregBair I need to parse this information to display it in a user friendly interface on a system dashboard.

Comment: @slinzerthegod that will not solve the issue.

Comment: @Guy I don't really understand what you want to do... Don't you want to read the file line by line?

Comment: @slinzerthegod, I want to read file error-by-error, rather than literally line by line.

Comment: Ah okay, then just remove all \n and then split it by date regexp.

Comment: @slinzerthegod so far this seems like the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression to match the start of the line. It usually is a date/time (timestamp).

This code works for me:

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents('/var/log/php-log.log');

    var_dump(preg_split('/\[\d\d-\w{3}-\d{4}\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\]/', $content));
```

But though i am splitting with the line-start pattern, the first result item would be empty.

Comment: `preg_split('/\[\d\d-\w{3}-\d{4}\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\]/', $error_log, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` doesn't return the delimiter itself. Any ideas why is it so?

Comment: because you need to add parentheses around the delimiter: `preg_split('/(\[\d\d-\w{3}-\d{4}\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\])/', $error_log, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

Comment: see this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#104602 and notice this:

`If this flag is set, **parenthesized** expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"\r\n"` and make sure they are in between double quotes.